# Trying to load a file into main activity's onCreate

Tags: android, file, kotlin

What I'm trying to do is test if the file "turma.dat" already exists, if it exists I just open it, if it does not exist, I create a new file and save it. When I start the app the first time it creates the file, but every time I start it again the file is created in white.

MainActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    var turma : Turma
    var file = File("turma.dat")

    if(file.exists()) {
        turma = this.abrirArquivo()
    }else{
        turma = Turma()
        ArquivoUtils(turma, this.applicationContext)
    }
```

Method abrirArquivo:

```
@Throws(IOException::class, ClassNotFoundException::class)
fun abrirArquivo(): Turma {

    val fis = this.applicationContext.openFileInput("turma.dat")
    val ois = ObjectInputStream(fis)

    return ois.readObject() as Turma
}
```

Class ArquivoUtils: (Responsible for receiving a Turma object add to a file and save)

```
class ArquivoUtils internal constructor( var turminha: Turma, var context : Context) {
internal val fos = this.context.openFileOutput("turma.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
internal val oos = ObjectOutputStream(fos)

init {
    this.salvarArquivo()
    this.closeFile()
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun salvarArquivo() {
    oos.writeObject(turminha)
    this.closeFile()
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
fun closeFile() {
    oos.close()
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "created in white"?

Comment: The file is empty.

Comment: so `File.exists("turma.dat")` returns true?  have you stepped through the code with a debugger?

Comment: I really do not know what's going on. I'm really confused about working with file on Android. I have worked a lot with file in desktop, but I do not know how to test if my file already exists in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file.exists()` is probalby not looking where you would expect.  Methods `openFileInput` and `openFileOutput` work on files in an application private location.  When you declare file you say...

```
var file = File("turma.dat")
```

Instead use something like...

```
var file = File(this.filesDir, "turma.dat")
```

See if that helps.  Read [Saving Files](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) to get a better grasp of how to work with files in Androidl

By the way, use a debugger and step through and verify that `file.exists` returns what you expect.  (If you don't know how to use the debugger, then start by learning how).

Comment: I tried to apply the changes you said, now when trying to open the app, it crashs.

Comment: that is probably progress.  what's the exception?  you can wrap your code in a try/catch block and print the exception.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.example.thial.estudandokotlin, PID: 10306
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.thial.estudandokotlin/com.example.thial.estudandokotlin.MainActivity}: java.io.EOFException

Comment: that's the logcat

Comment: EOFException - end of file or empty file, if you have a left over empty file from prior running your code, you probably have a bad file.  Delete the file (either explicitly, or by uninstalling your app), then try again.

Comment: I ran the app on my phone and it worked perfectly. But in the PC emulator it crashed.

Comment: EOFException means you are trying to read beyone End of File.  That would be your ObjectInputStream.  For ObjectInputStream to read an object, it must contain an object (`turma` in your case).  You have an empty file in internal storage.  It will not go away until you uninstall the app or explicitly call `file.delete()`.  Delete the file and try again.

Comment: I believe the problem is because there is a file in the PC project causing a problem. How can I delete the existing file in the project? On the phone I believe the problem solved by uninstalling the app.

Comment: The problem really was a file that was causing conflict. I uninstalled the app in the emulator and it is working. Your initial solution of changing my code by var file = File (this.filesDir, "turma.dat") solved the problem. thanks for your help and patience.